# About Add 7 days to existing date on IE code

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I want to use today's date to add `7` days.
I use the follow code is work on `Chrome` and `FireFox`.
But not work on IE, The IE display `Error`:

> Invalid Date.

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
var today = date.getFullYear()+'-'+ (date.getMonth()+1) +'-'+date.getDate();
alert(new Date(today));
```

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Which version of IE you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
new Date(Date.now() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7))
```

ms * sec * min * hr * days,

also you can simplify and store result of calculation as constant

Comment: This is the problem of using dash `-` in IE and Safari.

Comment: why use dashes, if you can just add milliseconds and get result without parsing, moreover if you use parsing from string it's requires more resources than getting date from timestamp. In any case my solution will be easier, understandable and require less resources, in all other browsers, not only in IE it would work as expected.

Comment: also he can avoid unnecessary calculation and create some constant: `const ONE_WEEK = 604800000` and it would be much faster than concatenations and parsing from string.

Comment: You are right no need to extra calculation. Just needed to indicate that `-` occurs problem in IE and safari.

Comment: Also to make ease. User friendly methods like `setDate` and `getDate` are provided

Answer (score 1):

It is becuase of using `-`, But you can just take `date` variable directly, As you already updating this.

```js
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
alert(date);
```

Check this [link](http://biostall.com/javascript-new-date-returning-nan-in-ie-or-invalid-date-in-safari/) to get more detail

Answer (score 0):

.setDate() method is unreliable at times. Most when using legacy versions of IE.
Use the following simple function that replicates the functionality of the .setDate() method. It simply generates a new date object based on the original date with the day of the month offset by the number of days passed in (positive or negative).

```

```
function addDays(startDate,numberOfDays)
        {
            var returnDate = new Date(
                                    startDate.getFullYear(),
                                    startDate.getMonth(),
                                    startDate.getDate()+numberOfDays,
                                    startDate.getHours(),
                                    startDate.getMinutes(),
                                    startDate.getSeconds());
            return returnDate;
        }
```

```